# Kentico - Using punctuation with AuthenticateUser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kentico

We are currently using version 7.0 of the kentico API to authenticate users into our system.

The following code is used to gain user details from the database and authenticate users.

```
UserInfo objUserInfo = AuthenticationHelper.AuthenticateUser(username.ToLower(), password.ToLower(), CMSContext.CurrentSiteName);
```

This has primarily been working correctly, but we are having issues with usernames and passwords that contain any of the following characters.

> " ! @ ' / \ > < * -

Is there any settings that I need to be aware of (web.config or otherwise) that would stop the API from accessing an account where a username or password contained special characters?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is according to the documentation. Check into this web.config key:

```
 <add key="CMSUserValidationRegEx" value="([A-Za-z0-9-]+)" />
```

Sets custom regular expression used for user name validation (used when new accounts are created or when existing usernames are modified).

The default value is "^[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.@]+$".

If the CMSEnsureSafeUserNames key is set to false, the following regular expression is used by default: "^[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.\\@]+$".

The only thing I can't tell for 100% is if it is purely for the AD Import of users or ALL users. It looks to be used on any call to ValidationHelper.IsUserName, so it is pretty safe to assume it is in play everywhere.

Source: http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/7_0/devguide/index.html?web_config_parameters.htm#forbidden_chars_users

Also the internal message when you try to create a user with those characters complains too. SO this would tell me that it is in play everywhere.

[image: Kentico 7 - Create User Error Message by Mcbeev]